# Как реализовать разбивку шаблонов?

Tags: angularjs

Здравствуйте.
Делаю маленькое приложение, чтобы набить руку.
[Код лежит здесь](https://github.com/YozhikM/branch/tree/master/livApp)

1. Нужно "разбить" отображение каждой "карточки" с матчем по разным страницам с переключением стрелочками.
2. По какой-то причине приложение не работает с ангуляром версии 1.6.4. С чем это связано и как исправить? 
   Update #1. Не работает .success, .then работает некорректно. Как исправить?

```js
var matchApp = angular.module('matchApp', []);

matchApp.controller('MatchCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('matches.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.matches = data;
    });
});
```

```css
.form {
width: 320px;
height: 480px;
margin-top: 2%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
font-family: 'Roboto';
color: white;
background: #E31B23;
border-radius: 20px;
}

.images {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-ms-flex-pack: distribute;
justify-content: space-around;
-webkit-box-align: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
align-items: center;
padding-top: 5%;
}

.home, .away {
width: 96px;
height: 96px;
}

.data {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
}

.data p {
margin-top: 5vh;
margin-left: 2vw;
font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="matchApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="MatchCtrl as match">
    <div class="form" ng-repeat="match in matches">
        <div class="images">
            <img ng-src="{{match.homelogo}}" class="home">
            <h1>{{match.result}}</h1>
            <img ng-src="{{match.awaylogo}}" class="away">
        </div>
        <div class="data">
            <p>{{match.round}}</p>
            <p>Дата: {{match.date}}</p>
            <p>Время: {{match.time}}</p>
            <p>Стадион: {{match.stadium}}</p>
            <p>Город: {{match.city}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: смотри ошибки в консоли. Скорее всего ошибка в использовании устаревшей функции success, которая была удалена в этой версии

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для перехода на карточку использован ui-router.
Импорт из JSON подключен следующим образом:

```
var livApp = angular.module('match-controller', []);

livApp.controller('MatchCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('matches.json').then(function (response) {
        $scope.matches = response.data;
    });
});
```